# Is it possible to add an indicator LED to a mains outlet?

Tags: led, mains, indicator

I am building a power filter/distributor for one of my HiFi systems. Nothing fancy, but I wanted to add an LED indicator for each outlet, signaling that a device is connected and is drawing current from said outlet.

The problem is that I’m not sure how and if there is a way to properly do this. I was first imagining the LED should be in series with neutral, but now that I think about it, I think I could use a Zener, a current limiting resistor, and the LED between neutral and Earth, so that a very small current would leak and light it up (guess an X rated cap would also be needed to prevent flickering).

I am not sure that’s either safe or sane. I am also open to the idea that it’s just not doable.

Comment: doesn't the HiFi system have power indicators?

Comment: Wasteful: use a low \$V_F\$ LED in series with a current limiting resistor, both in parallel to several high current diode oriented the same and a single anti-parallel one. Costly: use a current transformer or Hall effect sensing.

Comment: If you want to light up the LED if something draws current (opposed to lighting it up if voltage is present), you need to build some sort of current meter. Not the easiest of tasks, especially with mains voltage. Your idea with neutral and earth will certainly trip your buildings fault current circuit breaker, if you have one.

Comment: @jwsc didn’t think about that, good point. Does it trip from just a few uA?

Comment: @greybeard thanks for the sensor suggestion. Sounds interesting, I’ll look into that.

Comment: A few uA alone won't trip it but you need mA to light an LED and that may well do so. You're also adding to any other leakages already present in your house.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess I can either look for a suitable induction sensor or just use an ammeter gauge display as an indicator and either should be a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, here is a sketch of a solution.

For security reasons I would recommend that you use a current transformer to galvanically isolate your circuit from mains. Then you can connect the LED D1 in series with a current limiting resistor R. Antiparallel to D1 and R there should be another diode D2 to protect the LED from the negative half wave.

[image]

Comment: I like this solution, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could be of assistance :)

Answer (score -1):

That's a recipe for an explosive end to the device. Neutral and Earth are supposed to be the same voltage, although they often differ.

Additionally, messing around with mains sockets like that is a bad idea, even if only from an insurance POV.

Your best bet is to use a [mains power meter plug](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Monitor-Backlight-Electricity-Consumption-Analyzer/dp/B085S7Q1T4).

Comment: Ah, sorry, wasn’t clear enough I guess. Didn’t plan on messing with the wall outlet, but to build a separate box that includes filters. 

Not saying you’re wrong on the “explosive end” bit, but I would be grateful if you could explain why. Would love to understand.